# What should i use to authenticate my users in my REST API?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, jwt

I was planning on using JWT for the authentication of my users on my REST API (written with nodejs, using express), but i've seen people on the internet saying that it wasn't safe.

Is it really not safe ? What's a better alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

**passport** will best for authentication your user which will come on your application.

Comment: Which strategy ? I'm already using basic auth with passport but it's not secure.

Comment: i have no more idea about it but most of places and tuts" guide to us for passport js with socket.io this will confirm session  to socket.io then authentication with passport js. may be it will safe.

Answer (score 0):

JWT is just a token, not an authentication/authorization protocol. Using JWT can be secure or insecure it depends on how you use it.
JWT is the native token used by OIDC.
You're probably referring to the usual use of JWT as value tokens, which may be less secure than reference tokens.
See [here](http://nordicapis.com/api-security-oauth-openid-connect-depth/) for a somewhat clearer explanation.

In the comments you ask about using what is essentially basic HTTP authentication (only using JWT instead of uuencode(user:password) as the token). There is nothing wrong with basic authentication as long as the communication is properly secured (https using TLS >= 1.1), but there are severe limitations to using this type of authentication.
Any API authentication that requires username and password means every client of the app needs to have it's own user (principal). The whole stack of protocols on top of authentication in the paper I linked to is meant to solve several problems encountered by APIs. The two main ones are:

Federation: the user logs in once to a central system and does not need to log in again for each system that trusts the central system.

Delegation: the user delegates authority to a third party to allow it to do only specific tasks (and not others). This authority can be revoked individually without needing to change the permissions of other third parties or changing passwords.

Federation is the feature that lets you log with your Facebook or Google account to StackOverflow without providing your password. Delegation allows you to specify what  StackOverflow can do with your Facebook or Google account (e.g. get your personal info but not post). Delegation works on top of federation.

The problem with all this is that it makes your API more difficult to access: give the client a username and password vs. make the user using the client log in to an identity system and allow the client to use the API.
If your system is a B2B API with a single client application then using only authentication is fine. If your API involves users in any way or is meant to be consumed by third party applications then then you really have no choice but implementing the whole security stack (i.e. OIDC and OAuth). There is a (good) reason the stack was designed and it'll save you stumbling into the same problems it already solves.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about using JWT to authenticate my users using this kind of system : http://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/ . What do you think about it ?

Comment: response is too long for comment updating answer.

Comment: Can you send me a message ?

Comment: No, I can't I don't know what your API is about. The concern of authenticating users (i.e. who is accessing the API) is separate from authorisation (i.e. what can that person do). Under a delegation protocol, your API get's an opaque token, it get's forwarded to the authentication service and you get back the identity of the client. It is not at all certain your API needs to implement authentication. You could opt to use OAuth and have e.g. Google handle it, or a company like Auth0.

Comment: Well actually the thing I do right now is that I use basic auth. The user gives me his username+password, and I check if it exists, and it's type on the database. It's type is giving me what he can access and what he can't. My api is not designed to be used by anything but my mobile app and my web app. So I don't really about giving other services the right to use it.

Comment: In that case you are doing OK assuming the username+password is sent over a secure channel (https). However if you want to e.g. allow checkin using Google/Facebook/etc. or allow the user to know which mobile device logged in and revoke access to specific devices, then you should consider moving to OAuth + OIDC.

Comment: I'm already doing connexion via Facebook using the user's access token. I am doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use them. Json Web Token is *practically safe enough* as long as:

1. You sign it with a strong alg.
2. Keep the signing key safe from unauthorized access.
3. Don't store sensitive data in token itself.
4. Narrow down access scope of each token to only required resources.
5. Expire them soon enough.
6. Use TLS/SSL to transfer them securely.

Comment: Yeah but you see, you said "practically safe". I know nothing is unbreakable, but they must be something that is the top solution right now for authentication, right? What is everybody using?

Answer (score 0):

In most situations the security characteristics depend on the actual implementation rather than the specification or concept being used. You can have secure JWT implementations and you can also fail miserably...

Read [critical vulnerabilities in JSON Web Token libraries](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/) for some examples on JWT related vulnerabilities exposed by some implementations not because of the actual specification, but because how they implemented it and how developers ended up using them.

Authentication is a hard problem that's always evolving so secure implementations take time and resources to implement. If you really care about security **the best recommendation (alternative) is to delegate as much of it as possible** to someone or something completely focused on it.

This will also give you more time to focus on solving the business problems that made you start building your application in the first place. <sub>I would suggest a look at Auth0, but I like it so much that I ended up working there so I'm biased.</sub>

Comment: It felt like Auth0 could not be used by RESTful APIs.. plus I don't feel comfortable giving all my users to another service.

Comment: You can use services like Auth0 as the issuers of the tokens your REST API consumes. With tokens there's always two roles, an issuer and a consumer; the same entity can do both, but of course the complexity increases significantly. If you want to still manage user data yourself it's also possible to [configure it to use your own database](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database#using-a-custom-user-store) and let Auth0 handle just the protocol compliance and additional security measures.